# Zend Framework UnitTest

Tags: php, zend-framework

I tried to use Zend_Test_PHPUnit to write unit tests for my application, but I always just get

```
1) IndexControllerTest::testValidation
Failed asserting last controller used <"error"> was "test"
```

I have created a test controller but even there I cannot get it to work.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

```
class TestController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

   public function indexAction()
   {
        print 'test';
   }

}
```

Bootstrap is:

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
     || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

 // Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'testing'));

 // Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

phpunit.xml is:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php">
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory>./application</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="Library Test Suite">
        <directory>./library</directory>
    </testsuite>

    <filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory suffix=".php">../library/</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">../application/</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Test controller is

```
class IndexControllerTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testValidation()
    {
         $this->dispatch('/test/');
         $this->assertController("test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an error in your TestController.

Is your View available (/test/index.phtml)?

Good solution would be to check the thrown Exception (wrap the unit test in an Try/Catch Block and print to error log).

Comment: It was the missing view. I created just an JSON-API, this is why I didn't need the view.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the exact same error, but due to a completely different problem.

A more general solution might be to add this into the test method

```
    print_r(strip_tags(
        $this->bootstrap
             ->getBootstrap()
             ->getResource('layout')
             ->content
    )); die;
```

This is assuming that Zend_Layout is being used... It prints out the contents of the error.phtml file, so at least you can see exactly what is going on.

You should see something like:

```
An error occurred 
Application error 

Exception information: 

    Message: {Your Error Message will appear here}


Stack trace: 
    {A stack trace will follow...}
```

With your specific error message appearing after "Message:" and then a full stack trace after "Stack Trace:".

Hopefully this will at least help to debug the underlying issue